# Deprecated: mysql_pconnect():

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting an error during a php execution which i think it was due to a newer php 5.5 thing.

> Deprecated: `mysql_pconnect()`: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /public_html/mydomain.com/connx.php on line 7
>   Apr 3, 2014
>   checking

The inner code looks this way

http://justpaste.it/eyk2

So i thought changing the `mysql` to `mysqli` could solve the issue :

```
$conn = mysqli_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error("Server Down");
```

And instead, I'm getting this error... so i guess it was not the correct way of doing so :)

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `mysqli_pconnect()`

anyhow i can fix this issue ? The code was built long time ago and now i cant really get in touch with him :x

thanks
** UPDATED **
I changed the mysqli_connect and when i load the php script... it shows few errors now... just wondering do i have to change these syntax too ?

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Comment: you should read more of documentation on how to use PDO on php.net

Comment: Besides what @Quentin says, use variable binding technique (`WHERE name=?` -> `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`) instead of the old fashion stuff-everything-into-my-sql-statement `WHERE name='$name'`.

Answer (score 11):

See [the documentation for `mysql_pconnect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php):

> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> `mysqli_connect()` with p: host prefix

So use `mysqli_connect`, not `mysqli_pconnect` and modify the host argument as described

Answer (score 6):

There is no "mysqli_pconnect", but you can make persistent connections using `mysqli_connect()`  by adding `p:` to the beginning of the hostname.

So you can restore the old style by adding this to the head of your php file:

```
if (!function_exists("mysql_pconnect")){
    function mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password){
        return mysqli_connect("p:".$host, $username, $password);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE: As pconnects have nearly no benefit, you should replace `mysql_pconnect` with `mysql_connect` in your scripts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `mysqli_pconnect()`, but you can make persistent connections using `mysqli_connect()` as [described in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), simply by adding `p:` to the beginning of the hostname.

Quote from the manual:

> ```
> Prepending host by p: opens a persistent connection.
> ```

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem is actually the script is fetching some data, not sure if i hide this reporting, the fetching may fail or not.  (will not be using this hidden option)
In the mean time, i tried to edit it to mysqli_connect and more error when im running the script.. i guess this is gonna change as well ? 

mysql_select_db($database_conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

Comment: Yes, if you change one `mysql_` function call to `mysqli` then you must change them all -- they are completely separate database drivers (even though they ultimately talk to the same DB); you can't mix and match between them. A connection opened via mysqli can't be used by the mysql functions and vice-versa.

Comment: changing mysql_select_db($database_conn) to mysqli_select_db($database_conn) and mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8") to mysqli_query("SET NAMES UTF8");  ?

Comment: @user3493204: There are subtle differences between the mysql and mysqli APIs. for example, you will need to provide `$database_conn` as the first argument of `mysqli_query()`. Also note, that mysqli provides the [`mysqli_set_charset()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php), which replaces the need to make a `SET NAMES` query. See the manual page: quote: *This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem of having to update mysql_pconnect in an old script to make it run under php 7.0. I am not a php expert, so if you are not either, this may help you.

Typically the script will throw an error on mysql_pconnect because this is the FIRST obsolete function it finds, and then it halts. There may be many more assorted mysql_xxx functions which you have to find and fix.  Fortunately most of them can be fixed by a find-and-replace, replacing mysql with mysqli.

Exceptions are:
mysql_pconnect: I replaced this with mysqli_connect and added a fourth parameter, the database name.  (Mostly the persistence is not required).

mysqli_select_db: swap over the link and databasename parameters

mysqli_query:    swap over the link and databasename parameters

In all cases you should look up the old and new functions in the php manual to see what needs doing. Object-oriented usage is possible for the new functions but I ignored this and looked at the procedural examples.
My script now seems to work ok, so good luck!