# After a website migration i am getting an MySQL error Deprecated: mysql_pconnect():

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

sorry guys I don't really know much regarding PHP and I need a little help im migrating a website from one server to another and it seems the old server had an older version of OS and PHP
After moving over the files to the new server and the Databases I run the site and get

> Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /var/www/classes/dbcon.class.php on line 45

here is the code from that file I have tried changing a few lines and tried using the MySqli instead but I can't seem to get it working.

```
<?php



class dbCon
{
    //
    // private variables
    // 

    var $_hostname_Con;
    var $_database_Con; 
    var $_username_Con;
    var $_password_Con;
    var $_Con; 

    var $_result;   
    var $_hasData;
    var $_lastQuery;
    var $_row;
    var $_rowCount;

    //
    // methods (private)
    // 

    //
    // methods (public)
    // 

    // constructor
    function dbCon()

    {
        $this->_hostname_Con = "localhost";
        $this->_database_Con = "street";
        $this->_username_Con = "rt";
        $this->_password_Con = "mwL";
        //*
        $this->_database_Con = "cranes_cms";
        $this->_username_Con = "t";
        $this->_password_Con = "mob";
        //*/

        $this->_Con = mysql_pconnect ($this->_hostname_Con, $this->_username_Con, $this->_password_Con) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
        mysql_select_db($this->_database_Con) or die('Could not select database');
    }

    function freeResult()
    {
        mysql_free_result($this->_result);      
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysql_close($this->_Con);   
    }


    function update($inQuery)
    {
        //reset row counter and data flag
        $this->_rowCount = 0;
        $this->_hasData = FALSE;

        //do SQL
        $this->_lastQuery = $inQuery;
        mysql_query($this->_lastQuery,$this->_Con) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    function select($inQuery)
    {
        //reset row counter and data flag
        $this->_rowCount = 0;
        $this->_hasData = FALSE;

        //do SQL
        $this->_lastQuery = $inQuery;
        $this->_result = mysql_query($this->_lastQuery,$this->_Con) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

        //set has data flag
        if (mysql_num_rows($this->_result))
            {$this->_rowCount = mysql_num_rows($this->_result);}
        else
            {$this->_rowCount = 0; }

        if ( $this->_rowCount > 0) 
            {$this->_hasData = TRUE;} 
        else 
            {$this->_hasData = FALSE;}

    }

    function getData()
    {
    if ($this->_hasData)
        {
            if ($this->_row = mysql_fetch_array($this->_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {
                    return $this->_row;
                }
            else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
        }
    else
        {
        return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function getRowCount()
    {
        return $this->_rowCount;
    }   

    function hasData()
    {
        return $this->_hasData;
    }
// end 
}

?>
```

this is someone else's code and I'm not sure where to fix this. can anyone please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecated: mysql\_pconnect():](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22834458/6521116)

Comment: mysql_*() is deprecated.so use mysqli_*()

Comment: as I said I don't really know much regarding PHP and I have tried replacing the mysql_pconnect line with mysqli but it don't seem that simple

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using mysqli_*() you can learn more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if ($mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```